# Pass subclass of the class as a parameter in other class Swift

Tags: swift, class

i have three classes, class A:

```
class Game {
    init(tactic:Tactic) {
        //Set tactic
        tacticReference = tactic
        setShipsMapAndShotsMap()
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
class Tactic {
    var name:String?

    init() {
        name = "Default"
    }

   func shotPosition(shots: inout [[Int]],shipMap:[[Int]],ships:[Ship]) -> [Int] {
        return []
   }
}
```

And subclass of class B:

```
    class RandomTactic:Tactic {
override init() {
    super.init()
    name = "RandomTactic"
}

override func shotPosition( shots: inout [[Int]], shipMap: [[Int]], ships: [Ship]) -> [Int] {
    //Position
    var vertical:Int?
    var horizontal:Int?

    //Random position
    repeat{
        horizontal = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
        vertical = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    }while shots[vertical!][horizontal!] != 0

    //Fire at the position
    shots[vertical!][horizontal!] += 1

    return [vertical!,horizontal!]
}   
}
```

And I want to create `Game` object with class C instance as init parameter like that `let game = Game(tactic: RandomTactic)`  but Xcode give me an error `Cannot convert value of type 'RandomTactic' to expected argument of type 'Tactic'`. I want to create ships game and test a lot of different tactics so I have to do it like that, is there any solution?

Comment: RandomTactic() should have parenthesis

Comment: I forgot to add `()` in this line `let game = Game(tactic: RandomTactic)`, this is correct way `let game = Game(tactic: RandomTactic())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RandomTactic()` and not simply `RandomTactic`. In fact you want to inject an instance of a class that extends `Tactic`.

Anyway, I would create `Tactic` as a protocol instead of a class, since it's act as an abstract class (concept that Swift does not have).